# How to select an item which is not in other table?

Tags: sql

I want to select a language which is not translated yet.

omc_pages has

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lang_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

INSERT INTO `omc_pages` (`id`, `path`, ...`lang_id`) VALUES
(26, 'about_us',... 0),
(44, 'about_us', ...1)...
```

This means path, about_us has English and Norwegian already. I am assuming key 0 is English.

omc_languages has

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_languages` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `langname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `omc_languages` (`id`, `langname`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'norwegian', 'active'),
(2, 'french', 'active')...
```

So in this case I only want to get "french".

I tried this but gives an error.

```
SELECT * FROM omc_languages WHERE omc_languages.id NOT IN 
(SELECT lang_id FROM omc_pages WHERE omc_pages.path = $path)
```

I also think that right join may be able to do the job.

UPDATE: I my using MySQL. Error is the following.

```
Unknown column '$path' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM omc_languages WHERE omc_languages.id NOT IN (SELECT lang_id FROM omc_pages WHERE omc_pages.path = $path)
```

Comment: which database are you using?  what error does the bottom sql give?

Comment: I'm not sure what data you want to get out? Just all pages for a particular language? Or all the languages a particular path has?

Comment: What error do you get? Is it because `$path` isn't quoted? `NOT IN` should work as long as the sub query doesn't return any `NULL` s but the performance of subqueries in MySQL is pretty bad compared to JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
select distinct omc_languages.*
from omc_languages
left join omc_pages on omc_pages.lang_id = omc_languages.id
where omc_pages.id is null
```

But isn't really optimized. I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

well the statement you have written

```
SELECT * FROM omc_languages WHERE omc_languages.id NOT IN 
(SELECT lang_id FROM omc_pages WHERE omc_pages.path = 'about_us')
```

will give you all of the languages for which the string `path` in this case `about_us` is not translated for, if that's what you want. It seems you are having some problems with that @path variable.
But if you want languages which are not yet totally translated you can use similar way without the where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM omc_languages WHERE omc_languages.id NOT IN 
(SELECT lang_id FROM omc_pages )
```

Of course this is possible using a left join as well.

Answer (score -2):

Hi this is fairly simple to do with a right join:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.some_id = table2.some_id
WHERE table2.some_id IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this won't work, right join keeps only rows where data exist for the joining table (ie table2 in your example), so the result will always be empty.